# How to investigate very high kernel writes: 850GB of data in 44 days?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

This is what my current setup looks like:

[image]

It WROTE 850GiB onto my poor 128 GiB disk in 44 days.
I'm not quite sure what to make of that, especially since I use this machine for light browsing.

It means there's a whopping 20 gigs per day pushed down onto my (now) 9 years old SSD. 20% of the capacity is being rewritten all day long.

Do you guys know how I could investigate what is the reason for this amount of write?

Comment: I see kernel_task at 77GB after 5 days, so that would be 680 ish in 77 days. lsd however has written 376GB in the same period, 3300 in 77 days, potentially. Total write 869GB in 5 days.